# ¿Cómo llamar a una alerta o notificación para el usuario en la aplicación de Android?

Tags: android

¿Cómo llamar a la descripción o para la notificación de usuario en una aplicación para Android?

El problema es el siguiente:

Cuando el usuario hace clic en una opción que puede recibir una alerta diciendo que ha seleccionado determinado comando, opción en particular,

> ¿Cómo hacer una alerta de este tipo en una aplicación para Android?

Answer (score 3):

Un Toast no puede ser considerado especifícamente como una alerta, en realidad es como se comenta en la documentación:

> Un **Toast** proporciona información sencilla acerca de una operación en
>   una ventana emergente.

Este es pequeño ejemplo:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este es mi mensaje Toast!!! =)",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

En el cual podemos definir dos constantes que determinan la duración del toast.

> **LENGTH_LONG** Muestra la vista o notification por un largo periodo de
>   tiempo.
>
> **LENGTH_SHORT** Muestra la vista o notification por un corto periodo de
>   tiempo.

Otra opción es realizar un Toast personalizado:

```
LayoutInflater myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout,null);
Toast mytoast=new Toast(this);
mytoast.setView(view);
mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
```

#### Una notificación o alerta podría ser similar a una Push Notification.

Para ejemplo, he creado un método con el cual puedes crear dicha notificación, también agrego como crear un PendingIntent para que pueda recibir una Url la cual se abriría al dar clic en la notificación:

```
public static void creaNotificacion(long when, String notificationTitle,
                                      String notificationContent, String notificationUrl, Context ctx) {
    try {

        Intent notificationIntent;


        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        /* Valida la url y crea un Intent */
        if (!"".equals(notificationUrl)) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(notificationUrl));
        } else {
            notificationIntent = new Intent();
        }

        /* Crea PendingIntent */
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Construye la notificacion */
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                ctx).setWhen(when).setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(notificationTitle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Notificacion", "createNotification::" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

y este es un ejemplo de como llamar el método para crear la notificación, sería la forma de realizarlo cuando un usuario ha seleccionado determinado comando, la notificación aparecera :

```
creaNotificacion(0,"Notificación Android!","Como llamar a una alerta o notificación para el usuario en la aplicación de Android?", "http://es.stackoverflow.com", getApplicationContext());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al abrir la notificación desde la barra de notificaciones y puedes ejecutar una acción por medio de un PendingIntent, en este caso abrirá el url especificado !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Para la alerta rápida y breve, podemos hacer uso de `Toasts`:

El `toast` le permite mostrar un corto y rápido para el mensaje de usuario (sólo se utiliza con el texto).

Tomemos el ejemplo de una aplicación:

En mi paquete de aplicaciones `br.com.toasts`, el archivo `MainActivity.java`:

```
package br.com.toasts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void notify1(View v) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Aviso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }

    public void notify2(View v) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Aviso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.show();
    }

    public void notify3(View v) {
        Toast t = new Toast(this);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_toast);

        textView.setText("Aviso!");

        t.setView(view);
        t.show();
    }
}
```

---

En `carpeta layout` > Archivo `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="notify1"
        android:text="@string/btn_toast1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="notify2"
        android:text="@string/btn_toast2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="notify3"
        android:text="@string/btn_toast3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

En `carpeta layout` > Archivo `toast.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_toast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

En `carpeta values` > Archivo `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Toast</string>
    <string name="btn_toast1">Toast 1</string>
    <string name="btn_toast2">Toast 2</string>
    <string name="btn_toast3">Toast 3</string>
</resources>
```

En esta aplicación de ejemplo, hay tres tipos de alerta, como en la imagen de abajo:

[image]