# Cómo mandar notificación a una app desde la pc?

Tags: android

tengo una app a la cual le quiero mandar notificaciones cada que exista una nueva actualización de la misma, pero la quiero mandar desde mi pc o de alguna manera parecida. Es posible?.

Si no, de que manera puedo hacer las notificaciones remotamente?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Erick,  Si deseas se notifique sin entrar a la App sería mediante Push Notifications o un servicio que menciono en mi respuesta.

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias Elenasys

Comment: Me da mucho gusto Erick, saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementa GCM con [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/)

tu clase que reciba las notificaciones extendera de `FirebaseMessagingService` y dentro del método [onMessageReceived()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device) se recibirían las [Push Notifications](http://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/push-notification):

```
   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        crearNotificacion(notification);
    }
```

Esto es la opción ideal, la otra sería un **[servicio](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)** que estuviera constantemente leyendo la actualización de un archivo y tu implementarias la creación de la notificación.

Como un ejemplo, creas un archivo que tenga un dato el cual si cambia el servicio que constantemente revisa el archivo crea una notificación, para crear una notificación revisa esta respuesta: **["Como crear una notificación en android"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9995/95)**:

Answer (score 2):

Tu PC Como servidor? Montaría una base de datos para publicar la notificación de actualización, y programaría en la APP un código que al iniciar el `MainActivity` consultara en la base de datos del Servidor la actualización mas reciente.

Comment: Pero si quiero que notifique sin entrar a la APP, que simplemente llegue la notificación, como sería en ese caso?

Comment: Un comentario, aunque funcione, no es un muy buen enfoque por que para hacerlo asi, require consumir bateria de forma constante para repetir la consulta una y otra vez. Andorid trae un mecanismo llamado push notification. Todas las apps que usas lo utilizan, consta de un solo proceso interno encargado de recibir las notificaciones y enrutarlas a la app. Esto optimiza la bateria ya que todas las apps dependen de un solo mecanismo.